# The Suspend is Killing Me (14.0.3, 15.10, Elementary Freya) Acer Aspire E11

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, suspend, acer

Briefly I can't get this machine to suspend. Details and troubleshooting steps follow:

I bought a brand new Acer Aspire E11 ([http://www.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-ES1-111M-C40S-11-6-Inch-Diamond/dp/B00MNOPS1C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MNOPS1C)). I made Ubuntu USB sticks for LTS 14.0.3, 15.10, and even Elementary OS (derived from 14.0.3).

It installed perfectly until it came time for a restart. It hung on a black screen (with the backlight on) for literally 30 minutes before I just force rebooted the system (I assumed it might be doing something in the background).

Even after a reboot it never shuts down properly (I suspect this may be part of the issue).

Choosing Suspend from the far right (gear) blacks the screen out and it just sits there until the battery is dead.

Online searches offer a bunch of solutions for other machines, in many cases pointing to forums and other documents that are just mind bogglingly confusing. I tried a few very carefully without a shred of luck. From what I gather it may have something to do with the graphics hardware but 100s of articles later I can't be confident that's the cause.

I can bend Unix / OS X to my will but something as simple as getting a machine to suspend when I close the lid or click on the menu item is beyond elusive. This seems like a serious problem if any variant of Linux ever hopes to get consumer adoption.

Does anyone have a simple one or two step process that will fix this problem? Perhaps a pre-built script? This is just truly unusable at this point.

My mind is blown that something this simple isn't accounted for in the "checking hardware" part of the installation process.

I've tried every combination of settings in the BIOS GUI, and obviously I'm using legacy boot. Three days into begging this thing to work it's completely failing at something as simple as suspending. I'm about to suspend it in a large body of water.

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. I installed all updates both during install and immediately post install. I've enabled various repositories in Settings > Software & Updates without any luck. I think I've tried pretty much anything a technically advanced Ubuntu Noob can think of.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I had suspend issues on a different e series aspire and the solution was to update the BIOS.

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem on my acer e11 aspire (tried several linux distros). Aparently, the problem was using the BIOS firmware in legacy mode. Switching to UEFI mode in the BIOS menu solved all problems for me. I hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1.) Update the BIOS to the latest version.

2.) Reinstall Ubuntu, making sure to choose to install updates during the installation process, and install the 3rd-party software.

3.) Run

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

4.) Install the latest Intel Graphics drivers from: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0

This should fix the problem, assuming that the bug has been fixed in newer package versions.

Comment: A new version of the driver has come out, please install the latest version and retest (assuming the problem has not been fixed yet).