# Ubuntu version for game

Tags: 15.10, games, environment

Maybe I could find a lot of questions like that, but I need some help.

Recently I started using Ubuntu 15.10 , but when running games that consume few resources makes me very slow rendering of the game and several times I had to restart the computer because it can't complete tasks, even running task killers in terminal , I created windows live cd to verify that the problem is not rendering my computer, however surprise me take that in windows resource management with games going pretty well . I Really appreciate respond and help me find a solution , I don't have much experience in this system , but I really don't want to return to windows for a while .

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1545

Comment: Do you have any dedicated graphics card?

Comment: No, just the graphic card intel preinstalled

Comment: Would you be willing to use just plain Unity or maybe MATE? GNOME in't the heaviest desktop environment (KDE takes that place), but it's still somewhat resource-intensive. 3GB RAM should be able to run it, but you never know.

Comment: Drop Unity.  Look into `gnome-session-flashback` and possibly `cairo-dock`.

Comment: @earthmeLon That laptop is definitely capable of Unity.

Comment: @OP: If you really like GNOME, though, see if 14.04 works better.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've seen absolute performance by switching off of Unity for something else (Xfce4, gnome-session-flashback) and only offer it as a suggestion to further improve performance.

Comment: @earthmeLon Of course. I just don't think it needs to go that far yet. Since the performance is that bad, it could be a problem with the computer or the download, so going to vanilla Ubuntu is a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: Another thing you could try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/696932/the-suspend-is-killing-me-14-0-3-15-10-elementary-freya-acer-aspire-e11/719298#719298

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output if `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Zacharee1 good brother , thank you, you think I should then disconnect Unity to improve performance , or definitely recommend me switch to the version 14.04 , I do not really think it is problem of RAM because I just installed more memory to my lap , I Expandi memory to 8GiB in RAM. I was checking the official website of ubuntu and I ran into the distribution " Lubuntu " , do you think this version would give me better performance?

Comment: @smzamar Definitely try out Lubuntu. 8GB RAM is definitely better, but your processor is still pretty weak.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Do you think if I do "overclock" to the processor, the machine performance works better?

Comment: @smzamar I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thank you bro, you really help me, now, just a last question, are you really thinking that my best option is try to install a Lubuntu version, or maybe try with Ubuntu 14.04, with another performance? Actually I've the version 15.10 in 64bits, but, what do you think if I should try to install another version with another arquitecture?

Comment: @smzamar start out with normal Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity). If that doesn't work well, do MATE 15.10. If that isn't good, do MATE 14.04. If you still have performance issues, do Lubuntu 15.10. 14.04 is the next step. If it's still slow, try the 32-but version of GNOME 15.10, and trace back through this path again, just with 32-bit. I suspect, though, that your hard drive may be the problem. Have you ever replaced it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 no, I've never changed, why?

Comment: @smzamar The drive could be failing.